# Installing VMware vsphere 5 on multi raid array server

Tags: vmware-vsphere, raid5, raid1

We recently bought a new server that came with 2 600GB disks in a Raid 1 and 5 2TB disks in a raid 5.  Initially this was going run Windows Server 2008 R2, however, it was decided to now run VMware vsphere 5.  After I installed, I only see 1 datastore (the 2 600GB disks) in the vSphere client.  Is it possible to add the other raid array as a datastore? Is this something that I missed during the installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to Configuration->Storage->Add Storage, do you see the additional disk?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't just go ahead and format all disks, you'll need to select the host, then choose the Configuration tab, then Storage, select Add Datastore and follow your nose from there. Be aware that you're still limited to ~2TB .vmdk files even on a >2TB datastore.